# Save cell variable prior to setting header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following csv file which is displayed in excel as the following:

```
 A B C D E
1  x
2
3 a b c d e
4
5
```

where x is a value I need to save as a variable (specifically to add a new column 'f' in row 3 with the x value for all rows) and where row 3 (a,b,c,d,e) is the actual header row to be used.

I know you set the header during the .read_csv portion of the code but would I need to set the header = 0, save the variable, and then set header = 3? If so, how do I adjust the header after reading in the csv. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the file normally and adding the value "x" to row 3.
You can create a new df with that row's values as column names and ignoring the rows before the third row

```
headers = df.iloc[2]
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(df.values[3:], columns=headers)
```